# Example of system with equilibria that is Lyapunov stable and is non-isolated.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

I know that a Lyapunov stable equilibrium doesn't have to be isolated, but cannot think of a system of equations that satisfy this.

I also know that an equilibrium $x^*$ is Lyapunov stable: if $\forall\epsilon>0$ $\exists\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that when $|x-x^*|<\delta$ we have $|\phi(x,t)-x^*|<\epsilon$ for all $t\geq0$.

and $x^*$ is isolated if if there's a neighbourhood around it that has no other equilibria.

Comment: You mean something like the system with the "dynamics" $\dot{x}=0$ (namely very $x$ is an equilibrium)?

Comment: Just checking my understanding on lyapunov stability, since they system has equilibria for all x, then x* is lyapunov stable since there is essentially no flow?

Comment: Correct. It can be noted that it is also possible to construct examples where there is flow, but the set of non-isolated equilibria form a lower dimensional manifold (such as a circle in the 2D place). But the simplest example would I think be the one in my first comment.